# What does using a const assertion after a const string declaration do?

Tags: typescript

What's the difference between:

```
const CONSTANT = 'VALUE';
const object = { property: CONSTANT };
```

and

```
const CONSTANT = 'VALUE' as const;
const object = { property: CONSTANT };
```

In both cases, the type of `CONSTANT` is inferred to be `"VALUE"` (instead of as `string`). However, only in the second case, the type of `object` is inferred to be:

```
{
    property: "VALUE";
}
```

Instead of as:

```
{
    property: string;
}
```

I'm wondering why this is the case, even though in both examples, the type of `CONSTANT` is inferred to be `"VALUE"`.

Comment: `as const` is only ever going to give a _more_, not _less_, specific type. If you want a broader type, use `let` (because the value could change) or supply it explicitly.

Comment: I don't want a broader type, I just want the `p` in the return type of `func` to be inferred as `V1` or `V2`, instead of being inferred as `string`.

Comment: Oh, I see - `return {p: arg ? C1 : C2} as const`? Or just `return {p: arg ? C1 : C2}` if you used `as const` on `C1` and `C2` (which creates a "const context" where they don't get widened).

Comment: So that's my question. When I declare `const C1 = 'V1';`, the compiler already tells me that type of `C1` is `V1` (and not `string`, which is correct). Although the compiler tells me that the type of `C1` is `V1`, when I try to use it in an object, the type of the property in that object is inferred as `string`, instead of as `V1` or `V2`. Adding `as const` after declaration somehow prevents this. I'm wondering why adding `as const` prevents this. I edited the question to make it more clear what I'm asking.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the release notes for [TypeScript 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#better-inference-for-literal-types):

> When an expression of a literal type is inferred for a const location without a type annotation, that const variable gets a widening literal type inferred.

Under this rule, `const CONSTANT = 'VALUE'` has an apparent type of `"VALUE"` but whenever it gets used in a value-context, its type is automatically widened to `string`.

This behavior is consistent with the behavior of types narrowed by a type-guard or guard expression:

```
declare const CONSTANT: string;
if(CONSTANT !== "foo") throw "error";

// typeof CONSTANT is "foo" 
const object = { property: CONSTANT }
// typeof object is { property: string }
```

On the other hand `const CONSTANT = 'VALUE' as const` is not inferred as a literal type, instead it has a definite type provided by `as const`. It's equivalent to writing `const CONSTANT: "VALUE" = 'value'`.